# Viewing Geo-Map in Cisco SourceFire FireSight Defense Center

Tags: cisco-asa

Is there a way to view a geographical representation, specifically a map of network malware and intrusion events, within Defense Center?

Comment: This is OFF TOPIC for this Stack exchange.

Comment: Out of ignorance, how is this question off topic, given it pertains to a feature of a router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no actual map for viewing this information you can find it in the following area of the Defense Center web interface. The below pages will allow you to see attacks by continent and or country, as well as the ability to see more information on the types of attacks.

```
Overview > Dashboards > Summary Dashboard > Geolocation

Overview > Dashboards > Summary Dashboard > Intrusion Events
```

If there is not information available on those pages it is because you have not configured any widgets, which can be done via the toolbar midpage by clicking, "add widget."

Cisco Resource for Using Dashboards:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firesight/541/user-guide/FireSIGHT-System-UserGuide-v5401/Dashboard.html

General Firesight Documents Index Page:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/defense-center/tsd-products-support-configure.html

Comment: Thanks Brian for support. This is an answer that I was looking for. It is nice to see that someone is following and using the latest technologies and products from Cisco.